# Showing that the following set of functions forms a monoid on a base set X

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid of functions on a base set X. Define $S$ = {$f$: $X$ $\to$ $X$ | $m$ $\circ$ $f$ $=$ $id_X$ for some $m$ $\in$ $M$}. Show that $S$ is a monoid of functions on $X$.

Attempt:
I am confused about verifying even the closure axiom. So, I have taken two arbitrary functions $g$, $h$ $\in$ $S$ and to show that $S$ is closed, I think I have to verify that $m$ $\circ$ ($g$ $\circ$ $h$) $=$ $id_X$. What I did was following:

Let $s$ $\in$ $X$ be an arbitrary element in X. Then, to show closure I should show: $m$ $\circ$ ($g$ $\circ$ $h$) ($s$) $=$ $s$. Following by idea, I got, $m$ $\circ$ ($g$ $\circ$ $h(s$)) $=$ ($m$ $\circ$ $g$) $\circ$ $h$ ($s$) $=$ $id_X$ $\circ$ $h(s)$ = $h(s)$. I do not know what I am doing wrong, but I am not being able to verify closure. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that the “for some” is inside the description of $S$. That means that it is connected to the particular $f$. That is, each $f\in S$ establishes its membership in $S$ by exhibiting an $m$ (which may depend on $f$) such that $m\circ f=\mathrm{id}_X$. (By contrast, if the definition said “Define $S=\{f\colon X\to x\mid m\circ f=\mathrm{id}_X\}$ for some $m\in M$”, then the $m$ would be connected to $S$, and you would have the computation you attempt: the same $m$ is supposed be fixed and work for every $f\in S$. (In which case, it’s not a monoid for most choices of $m$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin wow I never realized such a subtlety in the specification of $m$. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin just a quick follow-up on this. What does it mean if set $S$ is defined as $S$ = {$f$: $X \to X$ | $m \circ f = id_X$}. The set notation does not say anything about $m$. Neither is there any description of $m$ after the set is defined.

Comment: If $m$ is *never* specified, then it’s a nonsensical definition. You need it either explicitly specified, qantified, or somehow clearly understood from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show $g \circ h \in S$, on the basis that $g, h \in S$. Your error is assuming that there is one $m$ such that $m \circ g$ and $m \circ h$ are both simultaneously equal to $\operatorname{id}_X$, and requiring that this same $m$ work for $g \circ h$ too.

Instead, you may assume $m \circ g$ and $n \circ h$ are both equal to $\operatorname{Id}_X$, where $m, n \in M$, and construct a different $p \in M$ such that $p \circ (g \circ h) = \operatorname{Id}_X$. The construction of $p$ will have to feature both $m$ and $n$. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: I think I got it. I defined by $p$ to be $n \circ m$.

Comment: @Ufomammut That's right. :-)

Comment: A quick question. One of the confusions that I always have for proving associativity in these sorts of questions is "Should I use the information about the set $S$ given in the question?" What I am trying to ask is: Does showing associativity simply mean showing $f \circ (g \circ h)$ = $(f \circ g) \circ h$, in which case I can simply take it for granted using the idea of function composition?

Comment: @Ufomammut That's all you have to show. Associativity is inherited from the larger monoid of functions from $X$ to $X$. We're only restricting which functions we play with, but $f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h$ continues to hold in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.